# Visual Studio Code Unreal Engine

Tags: visual-studio-code, unreal-engine4

Does anyone know which extensions I've got to download in order to let Visual Studio **Code** work properly with Unreal Engine?

Comment: You don't need any extensions. The C/C++ extension is okay for code navigation and basic features, but it's a bit slow and inaccurate. Personally I like to use ClangD, but for that you'll need to run the UBT with -mode=GenerateClangDatabase to create a new compile_commands.json. ClangD also doesn't work with unity builds and there's not much info out there on getting it working so the C/C++ extension is definitely the quicker plug&play style option.

Answer (score 1):

Most people use the Microsoft C++ extension.

I also created an extension that fixes some of the problems that the UE creates when it makes a VSCode project.
https://gist.github.com/boocs/f63a4878156295b6e854cac68672f305

Just know that intellisense is slow in header files but decently fast in source files once intellisense loads. It takes ~30 seconds to load when switching to a source file.

Answer (score 0):

I Have the C/C++ Extension Pack installed also the UE Intellisense fixes that fixes some UE vscode issues , you can find more on how to install on github : https://gist.github.com/boocs/f63a4878156295b6e854cac68672f305

Answer (score -2):

You can install some extension for Visual Studio Code to make it works with UE. But anyways, the best method is to download and install Visual Studio.
You can find more information about Visual Studio here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/